# Which browsers should I be using to test my webpage?

Tags: browser, web

I've tested my page in Chrome (Mac), Firefox (all), Safari (all), IE9 (Win 7), and Opera (Mac). I'm also planning to do Chrome for Windows and Chromium for Linux, and Opera for Windows. Are there any others (for desktop) with wide enough usage that I should download and test with them?

Comment: Depends on what you seek. What features are you testing? Do you want to guarantuee that will just work between all browsers, or you want to behave identically on all of them? It also depends on what features you plan to have/se (HTML5, CSS3?)? Will you use flash?

Comment: HTML 4.01 strict, CSS, jQuery. I just want it to work properly on all browsers (foresee any "IE box model bugs" of other browsers).

Comment: You may want to test some smartphones also, tablets and consoles (ps3, psvita, 3ds). It all depends on which type of website are you developing and what is the expected type of users.

Comment: For those, I'd say you test on at least on Dolphin for Android and the default android's browser. You should be fine with those.

Comment: @SHiRKiT I'm planning on the included browser, dolphin, and firefox for Android. I've done Safari, Chrome, Mercury, and Firefox Home for iOS, and the default and only on Wii and 3DS, as I have access to those.

Comment: HTML4? What a joke. That is ***old***…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always found the best policy is to test in IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari (latest versions) then install a service like Google Analytics to find out what other browsers you are popular on. Testing across all different operation systems can be very time consuming and you might be surprised at the breakdown your site has for traffic.

Comment: +1 You should use some web analytics to see which browsers and browser versions are popular on your site.

Comment: I'm doing this all before it goes live, but I will keep that in mind for when it launches. +1

Comment: IE 10+ will typically be like the other modern browsers, thought it will still have its quirks.  Develop mostly using Chrome/IE 9 and you'll be good.  IE 7, 8, and 9 all have their own quirks, though, so it will be up to you whether you want to support those are not.  I consider 6 and 7 to be lost causes, even though there's still a decent user base on 7.

Answer (score 1):

Use this link to get a good feeling on browser usage trends:
http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp
Keep in mind that these statistics are based on this particular site users, which are suspected to be a bit more 'tech-savvy' then normal users. If you click a specific browser you will see the statistics for the browser's different versions. for example, you can see that around 8% of the site's users use IE8, which is not in your list.

Also, use this site:
http://caniuse.com/
To check for support of specific HTML / CSS elements throught the different browsers.

Don't forget to provide your website users with proper fall back content for every element that's not  supported in older browser versions.